# Event handler not working with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is a much simpler and modified part of my original code.

---

Anytime I call an event it doesn't function, I have tried too many times. Any help
would be appreciated.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function hello ()
    {
        alert("Hello!!!");
    }
</script>
<div id="platform">
    <div id="mainOval">
        <form id="btns">
            <input type="button" value="Timer" id="timerBtn" onclick=hello()/>
            <input type="button" value="Countdown" id="ctDownBtn" onclick=hello()/>
        </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be :

```
onclick="hello()" instead of onclick=hello()
```

you could even use it as

`onclick="alert('Hello')"`

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

- don't use inline `on*` JavaScript handlers like `onclick`, it's considered unsafe and hard to debug.
  JavaScript scripts should be in one place only, and those are the respective tags or files. Instead, use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- semantics-wise, use rather `<button type="button">` instead of `<input type="button">`
- place your non-defered `<script>`s in a non-blocking manner, right before your closing `</body>` tag. Not in head and not anywhere else.

```html
<body>
  <div id="platform">
    <div id="mainOval">
      <form id="btns">
        <button type="button" id="timerBtn">Timer</button>
        <button type="button" id="ctDownBtn">Countdown</button>
      </form> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
  function hello () {
    alert("Hello!!!");
  }
    
  document.querySelectorAll("#timerBtn, #ctDownBtn").forEach(elBtn => {
    elBtn.addEventListener("click", hello);
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

Additional resources:

- [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [NodeList.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)